# What is that type of light in the picture?

Tags: night, nightclubs

Is it flash ? or just LED ring light ??
[image: Ring]

Answer (score 1):

A flash light can be made from leds. The diference would be if it lights on a single strobe or in a continuous mode.

That is definetly a "ring" made of leds. If was used as a strobe or as a continuous light is hard to know. (But I suspect it is the second option)

A continuous light can be used on video.

But on a still photography you could try to gess reading the exif from the photo.

Comment: Since the diffraction flares on the LEDs are a different angles, suggesting at least three separate exposures, I suspect that the ring-led was Photoshopped in, and the main light source was probably a conventional flash. Certainly, some image manipulation on the ring-led has been performed.

Comment: @Mick I don't think it was shopped. The main source was the ring light due to light balance of the hair and the catchlights in the eyes have only the ring source. No other highlights are evident ruling out the use of a second source. A conventional flash would have introduced other lighting artifacts not evident here. It appears to be approximately 24 to 30 inches or more in diameter.

Answer (score 0):

This is an LED ringlight.
Homemade. I made one as well.
All the clubs in dubai Prefer if you use one when shooting gigs in there.

-5050 Led strip or similar
-Battery pack
-Dimmer (helps with exposure)
-Pipe (Hulahoop type etc Or smaller if preferred)

Comment: First, HOW did you know it is in Dubai  ? Second, can you please put some tutorial links? Youtube?

Thanks